# Setup Amazon EC2 server for iOS push notifications

Tags: ios, amazon-ec2, apple-push-notifications

I'm kind of new on virtual servers setup. I'm using Amazon Web Services (AWS) to create an EC2 instance (virtual server) which I'm able to connect using PuTTY and WinSCP. I want to setup the virtual server to use it for an iOS app push notifications service. I was using this tutorial to learn how to implement push notifications in iOS: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2

This tutorial uses a local host instead of a virtual server, so I want to know how to setup an Amazon Virual Server to use it for push notifications. Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial they are setting up MAMP, which is basically a combination of:

- apache (a web server)
- my sql (a sql database)
- and php (a server side language)

If you want to follow the tutorial you will then have to install apache, mysql and php separately. The procedure should then be quite similar (you will obviously add to do some adjustments, but not much). The procedure may also change according to the OS of your server (EC2 instance).

Make sure to replace `localhost` by the public dns property of your EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes, I know what MAMP and WAMP is. The OS of my server is Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09.2 64bits, but I don't know the procedure in this case because there's also a key pair for authentication, as I said I'm kind of new in servers. Also, is this the public DNS property? (ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com) replacing the "X's" whit the ip provided. It would be great if there's some tutorial for the procedure using virtual servers, or if you can explain some way. Thanks! :) (BTY, I already know how to edit the httpd.conf file in my virtual server)

Comment: The key-pair authentication is for ssh access only (so basically you connecting to your server using ssh). You must think of your virtual server as a normal machine without UI, you login using ssh. Then it's like your machine. Check how to install mysql, php and apache, then you can follow the tutorial. To make it work you will have tto open the appropriate ports on your EC2 instance using security groups, but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to setup my server! I used this tutorial: http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2011/03/getting-php-mysql-running-amazon-ec2/

Answer (score 0):

The idea is the same between `localhost` and whatever server you are working on. `localhost` is just another name for to `127.0.0.1` which is always your own machines IP. You can just replace anything in a URL that says `localhost` with the IP or domain name of your server, as long as you have setup your server right to be able to handle these requests.

Comment: Well thats exactly what I don't know how it's done, the server setup part.